# Internal Error: Could not find .pro file

Tags: android, c++, qt, build, compilation

I'm cross-compiling library for android using qt-opensource-windows-x86-android-5.4.0.

But I can't more compile.. I don't know why..

Below is error messages.

```
09:25:16: Internal Error: Could not find .pro file.

Error while building/deploying project cmirisLib (kit: Android for armeabi-v7a (GCC 4.9, Qt 5.4.0))

When executing step "Build Android APK"
```

This is not application. I want to get a 'lib[libraryname].so' for android.

Could you help me?

Regards,

UK

Answer (score 2):

In my case, this problem was caused because I was porting a program to Android from Desktop environment. In Android your launcher is not an executable file but a lib. However, you must ensure that you get an entry point and for that QMake seems to somehow require that at least some project in the build tree has

```
TARGET = app
```

in order to build/deploy correctly in Android. So, I had to add something like this to the .pro file

```
TEMPLATE = lib  # for the Desktop (Lin/Win/Mac) this is a "lib"

android {
    TEMPLATE = app  # for Android this is an "app"
}
```

I addition, I guess it is worth reminding that you might need to provide a main() function (which you could had left outside the code).

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

According to this :
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-13566
Disable the "Make Install" and "Build Android APK" Steps from within the kit settings.